# How do i write a matlab code that asks to input a funtion, and then uses that function in the rest of the program?

Tags: matlab, bisection

I want to write a matlab code that asks for us to enter a function, number of iterations and two endpoint values , and then uses bisection method to solve for the roots of the function. I have looked at alot of matlab codes for the bisection method but they all use the function already defined in the program.

Comment: In one minute: http://www.math.ohiou.edu/courses/math3600/lecture5.pdf,  https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~dwharder/NumericalAnalysis/10RootFinding/bisection/matlab.html, https://www.math.washington.edu/~greenbau/Short_Course_in_Hanoi/bisect.m, https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/33748-bisection-method/content/bisection.m,

Answer (score 1):

Let's take [this example](https://www.math.washington.edu/~greenbau/Short_Course_in_Hanoi/bisect.m) (thx, Moo). It defines the function `f` at the end. Delete that bit, and modify the first line to be `function c = bisect(f, a, b, delta)`.

This new `bisect` can be called with something like

`f = @(x)cos(x); disp(bisect(f, a, b, delta))`

or with

`disp(bisect(@f, a, b, delta))`

if `f` is defined in a file `f.m`.

Look for topics 'anonymous functions' and 'function handles' in MATLAB for more.